# Efficient way to overwrite data in the middle of an mmapped file

Tags: c++, file-io, hashmap, mmap

I have a text file that is being concurrently written to by one program, and read from by another. The file itself is a bunch of key-value pairs, where each pair is on its own line, and the key and value are separated by a whitespace. I have mmapped the file into both program's memories (using the MAP_SHARED flag), and I have succeeded in getting the program that needs to write to the file to write to it very efficiently when the key of a new user-provided key-value pair does not already exist in the file.

What I am struggling with now is efficiently overwriting the value associated with a key when a new key-value pair is entered by the user and the key already exists in the file.

When the new value is the same or fewer bytes than the original, I can simply overwrite the value at the mapped address and I don't have to worry about munmapping and mmapping again. However, is there an efficient way to deal with this when the new value would be larger than the previous value?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do that. You may want to consider using a proper database.

Comment: I would love to, but the constraints of the project, which is more of an exercise, is concurrent reading and writing of a file by two programs, where the file stores key-value pairs, one program can add/edit those key-value pairs, and another program can simply retrieve values associated with keys that exist in the file. Essentially a concurreny-friendly hash map living in a file.

Comment: @AlexanderBolinsky Dude its one hell of a task.. I mean what you are trying to do is a very huge debate in the CS or DB world.

Comment: A hashmap cannot store variable-sized data. At most it can store pointers to same.

Comment: I guess in the cases where the key doesn't exist - or the key does exist but the new value is larger than the original value - I can simply overwrite the entire file with the entries in an actual hash map in the writer? Then munmap and mmap again?

Comment: @AlexanderBolinsky and you need live consistency like if what the reader is reading and while reading it it gets modified by the writer then the reader needs new old values or the new ones?

Comment: @MubashirHanif I am dealing with that by having the writing program hold a lock on the file while it is trying to write/overwrite a pair, and if the reader requests a value during this time, they will stall until the file is available for reading.

Comment: One thing that may help is that I know the value can never be longer than 10 characters. So maybe I can ensure that the writer always writes 10-character long values. Smaller values can just have whitespace appended to the end of them. This would make my life incredibly easy. It would be a little inefficient with actual space, but the efficiency gained with speed may be worth it.

Comment: @AlexanderBolinsky I am afraid it won't be possible. you can't write to the specific portion of the file without actually searching the file for where to write. or you have to completely overwrite the file with in-memory hash. either way there won't be a drastic change in speed.

Comment: @AlexanderBolinsky But there is a trick you can apply.. it might be slower or faster I can't guarantee.. depends on your file size. and that method will only work or speed things up if you have huge files. I mean literally huge.

Comment: @MubashirHanif In my writing program, I am keeping a hash map where the keys are the keys in the file, and the values are pointers to the addresses in the mmapped file. So when I am looking to insert a new key-value pair, or update an existing one, I don't search through the whole file again, I simply look up the corresponding address in constant time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92456/discussion-between-mubashir-hanif-and-alexander-bolinsky).

Comment: **What** are the constraints of the projects? I think it's relevant information, without telling you're likely to get suggestions that violate the constraints.

Comment: @skyking All of the constraints of the project are what I wrote in my post and the first comment. Keys can have a value from [0,2^16), and values can have a value from [0,2^32). I must memory map the file into both programs. One program has read/write permissions, and the other program only has read permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Since key and values have restricted values you could pad them so that you don't need lines of variable length - just make room for 5 digits for the key and 10 digits for the values.

Then of course you have the problem with which guarantees the memory mapped regions are in sync and how to avoid race conditions. For example posix doesn't seem to give any guarantees what the other (reader) program sees between the write and the `msync` call.

You would then have to add some syncronization information in the file. This could for example be done by making sure that the value is invalid during update. For example using zero-padded value and putting a 5 as the first digit could be used as an indication that the value is under update. You have to be careful though not to assume things that are not guaranteed.

Comment: You should use mutexes if you're going to write and read from a shared memory region concurrently. If you want to get into lock-free programming by doing what @skyking suggests with invalid values, you need to worry about alignment, atomicity, processor and programming language memory models, synchronized instructions like with the x86 lock prefix, etc. This is beyond what most programmers are willing to do, and beyond the ability of most who attempt it. You'd better have a really good reason if you go down that road.